# how to send tenantid to downstream services when using ocelot with abp

Tags: abp, ocelot

I am currently using ABP and ocelot to build a api gateway for microservices. Everything works fine but now I want to use api gateway as a domain resolver. ABP's Domain Resolver works to resolve tenantid from different domains but i want ocelot to able to send the resolved tenant id to the downstream services(Include __tenant header in the headers of the request to the downstream service).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `Middleware` for adding `ResolvedId` to the request headers. So the ocelot will send the edited request to downstream with the `tenantId`.

Example:

```cs
public class MyMiddleware : IMiddleware, ITransientDependency
    {
        private readonly ICurrentTenant CurrentTenant;

        public MyMiddleware(ICurrentTenant currentTenant)
        {
            CurrentTenant = currentTenant;
        }

        public Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
        {
            context.Request.Headers.Add("__tenant", CurrentTenant.Id.ToString());

            return next(context);
        }
    }
```

As you see, the middleware manupilates the request, it's adding the CurrentTenantId to the request.
The CurrentTenant is found before by your "domain tenant resolver".

You can use this middleware between `app.UseMultiTenancy()` & `app.UseOcelot()`

```cs
...
app.UseMultiTenancy();

app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>(); // it must be here, between them

app.UseOcelot();
...
```